# How to disable WordPress plugin updates except for one admin

Tags: wordpress

I'm a newbie in coding and I would like to disable WordPress plugin updates for other admins except for the admin with the username: webadmin. I tried the following codes but it disabled plugin updates for all admins.

Can anyone enlighten me what is the issue here?

```
function remove_core_updates () {
     global $wp_version;
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

     if ($current_user->user_login == "webadmin"){
     return(object) array(
          'last_checked'=> time(),
          'version_checked'=> $wp_version,
          'updates' => array()
     );
     }
}

add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins','remove_core_updates');
```

I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: If I don't want to give users access to plugin updates etc I normally just make them an Editor.

Comment: A solution is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783122/hide-plugins-for-all-users-except-specified-admin-in-wordpress